# Interger value from a textfield win32 api

Tags: c++, winapi, int, codeblocks, textfield

I am a noob spelling it out will help.
Using c++ win32 api i  need to get an int variable from a textfield to control a for loop.

I have my button,  textfields  and, variables all setup. I just need "Textfield1" given to "int LVL1" and "Textfield2" given to "int LVL2".

I basically have no idea where to start, tried searching here and other places and keep getting char or java answers.g

I got this far what am I doing wrong?
GetDlgItemInt( TextField1, LVL1, NULL, false);
But doesn't change the value.

CODE:

case WM_CREATE:{ TextField1 = CreateWindow("Edit", "Current Lvl",

TextField2 = CreateWindow("EDIT", "Desired Lvl",

Button = CreateWindow("BUTTON", "Submit",

break; } case WM_COMMAND:

if(LOWORD(wParam == 1)){system("echo \"Submit\" Button"); ///Used for debuggin only int souls[793] = {0, 0 , 673 , 690 , 707 , 724 , 741 , 758 , 775 , 793 , 811 , 829 , 847 , 1039 , 1238 , 1445 , 1660 , 1883 , 2114 , 2353 , 2601 , 2857 , 3122 , 3396 , 3678 , 3970 , 4271 , 4581 , 4900 , 5229 , 5567 , 5915 , 6273 , 6641 , 7019 , 7407 , 7805 , 8214 , 8634 , 9064 , 9505 , 9957 , 10420 , 10894 , 11379 , 11876 , 12384 , 12904 , 13436 , 13979 , 14535 , 15103 , 15683 , 16275 , 16880 , 17497 , 18127 , 18770 , 19426 , 20095 , 20777 , 21472 , 22181 , 22904 , 23640 , 24390 , 25154 , 25932 , 26724 , 27530 , 28351 , 29186 , 30036 , 30901 , 31780 , 32675 , 33585 , 34510 , 35450 , 36406 , 37377 , 38364 , 39367 , 40386 , 41421 , 42472 , 43539 , 44623 , 45724 , 46841 , 47975 , 49126 , 50294 , 51479 , 52681 , 53901 , 55138 , 56393 , 57666 , 58956 , 60265 , 61592 , 62937 , 64300 , 65682 , 67082 , 68501 , 69939 , 71396 , 72872 , 74367 , 75881 , 77415 , 78969 , 80542 , 82135 , 83748 , 85381 , 87034 , 88707 , 90401 , 92115 , 93850 , 95606 , 97382 , 99180 , 100999 , 102839 , 104700 , 106583 , 108487 , 110413 , 112361 , 114331 , 116323 , 118337 , 120373 , 122432 , 124514 , 126618 , 128745 , 130895 , 133068 , 135264 , 137483 , 139726 , 141992 , 144282 , 146596 , 148933 , 151295 , 153681 , 156091 , 158525 , 160984 , 163467 , 165975 , 168508 , 171066 , 173649 , 176257 , 178890 , 181549 , 184234 , 186944 , 189680 , 192442 , 195230 , 198044 , 200884 , 203751 , 206644 , 209564 , 212511 , 215484 , 218485 , 221513 , 224568 , 227650 , 230760 , 233897 , 237062 , 240255 , 243476 , 246725 , 250002 , 253307 , 256641 , 260004 , 263395 , 266815 , 270264 , 273742 , 277249 , 280785 , 284351 , 287946 , 291571 , 295226 , 298910 , 302625 , 306370 , 310145 , 313950 , 317786 , 321652 , 325549 , 329477 , 333436 , 337426 , 341447 , 345499 , 349583 , 353699 , 357846 , 362025 , 366236 , 370479 , 374754 , 379061 , 383401 , 387773 , 392178 , 396616 , 401086 , 405590 , 410127 , 414697 , 419300 , 423937 , 428607 , 433311 , 438049 , 442821 , 447627 , 452467 , 457341 , 462250 , 467194 , 472172 , 477185 , 482233 , 487316 , 492434 , 497587 , 502776 , 508000 , 513260 , 518556 , 523887 , 529255 , 534659 , 540099 , 545575 , 551088 , 556637 , 562223 , 567846 , 573506 , 579203 , 584937 , 590708 , 596517 , 602364 , 608248 , 614170 , 620130 , 626128 , 632164 , 638238 , 644351 , 650502 , 656692 , 662921 , 669188 , 675495 , 681841 , 688226 , 694650 , 701114 , 707617 , 714160 , 720743 , 727366 , 734029 , 740732 , 747476 , 754259 , 761084 , 767949 , 774855 , 781802 , 788790 , 795819 , 802889 , 810001 , 817154 , 824349 , 831586 , 838864 , 846185 , 853548 , 860953 , 868400 , 875890 , 883422 , 890997 , 898615 , 906276 , 913980 , 921727 , 929517 , 937351 , 945229 , 953150 , 961115 , 969124 , 977177 , 985274 , 993415 , 1001601 , 1009831 , 1018106 , 1026426 , 1034790 , 1043200 , 1051655 , 1060155 , 1068700 , 1077291 , 1085927 , 1094609 , 1103337 , 1112111 , 1120931 , 1129797 , 1138710 , 1147668 , 1156674 , 1165726 , 1174825 , 1183971 , 1193164 , 1202404 , 1211691 , 1221026 , 1230408 , 1239838 , 1249316 , 1258841 , 1268415 , 1278037 , 1287707 , 1297425 , 1307192 , 1317007 , 1326871 , 1336784 , 1346746 , 1356757 , 1366817 , 1376927 , 1387085 , 1397294 , 1407552 , 1417860 , 1428218 , 1438626 , 1449084 , 1459592 , 1470151 , 1480760 , 1491420 , 1502131 , 1512892 , 1523705 , 1534569 , 1545484 , 1556450 , 1567468 , 1578537 , 1589658 , 1600831 , 1612056 , 1623333 , 1634662 , 1646044 , 1657477 , 1668964 , 1680503 , 1692095 , 1703740 , 1715438 , 1727189 , 1738993 , 1750851 , 1762762 , 1774727 , 1786746 , 1798818 , 1810945 , 1823126 , 1835361 , 1847650 , 1859994 , 1872392 , 1884845 , 1897353 , 1909916 , 1922534 , 1935207 , 1947936 , 1960719 , 1973559 , 1986454 , 1999405 , 2012412 , 2025475 , 2038594 , 2051769 , 2065001 , 2078289 , 2091634 , 2105036 , 2118495 , 2132010 , 2145583 , 2159213 , 2172900 , 2186645 , 2200447 , 2214307 , 2228225 , 2242201 , 2256235 , 2270327 , 2284478 , 2298686 , 2312954 , 2327280 , 2341665 , 2356109 , 2370612 , 2385174 , 2399795 , 2414476 , 2429216 , 2444016 , 2458876 , 2473796 , 2488775 , 2503815 , 2518915 , 2534075 , 2549296 , 2564577 , 2579919 , 2595322 , 2610786 , 2626311 , 2641897 , 2657545 , 2673253 , 2689024 , 2704856 , 2720750 , 2736706 , 2752724 , 2768804 , 2784946 , 2801151 , 2817418 , 2833748 , 2850141 , 2866597 , 2883115 , 2899697 , 2916342 , 2933050 , 2949822 , 2966657 , 2983556 , 3000519 , 3017546 , 3034637 , 3051792 , 3069012 , 3086295 , 3103644 , 3121057 , 3138535 , 3156078 , 3173686 , 3191359 , 3209097 , 3226901 , 3244770 , 3262705 , 3280706 , 3298773 , 3316905 , 3335104 , 3353369 , 3371700 , 3390098 , 3408562 , 3427093 , 3445691 , 3464356 , 3483088 , 3501887 , 3520754 , 3539687 , 3558689 , 3577758 , 3596895 , 3616100 , 3635373 , 3654714 , 3674123 , 3693601 , 3713147 , 3732762 , 3752446 , 3772199 , 3792020 , 3811911 , 3831871 , 3851900 , 3871999 , 3892167 , 3912405 , 3932713 , 3953091 , 3973539 , 3994057 , 4014646 , 4035304 , 4056034 , 4076834 , 4097705 , 4118647 , 4139660 , 4160744 , 4181899 , 4203126 , 4224424 , 4245795 , 4267236 , 4288750 , 4310335 , 4331993 , 4353723 , 4375525 , 4397400 , 4419347 , 4441367 , 4463460 , 4485626 , 4507865 , 4530177 , 4552563 , 4575021 , 4597554 , 4620160 , 4642840 , 4665594 , 4688422 , 4711324 , 4734300 , 4757351 , 4780476 , 4803677 , 4826951 , 4850301 , 4873725 , 4897225 , 4920800 , 4944450 , 4968176 , 4991977 , 5015854 , 5039807 , 5063836 , 5087941 , 5112122 , 5136380 , 5160713 , 5185124 , 5209611 , 5234175 , 5258816 , 5283534 , 5308329 , 5333201 , 5358151 , 5383178 , 5408284 , 5433466 , 5458727 , 5484065 , 5509482 , 5534977 , 5560550 , 5586202 , 5611932 , 5637741 , 5663629 , 5689596 , 5715642 , 5741767 , 5767972 , 5794255 , 5820619 , 5847062 , 5873585 , 5900188 , 5926871 , 5953634 , 5980477 , 6007401 , 6034405 , 6061491 , 6088656 , 6115903 , 6143230 , 6170639 , 6198129 , 6225700 , 6253353 , 6281087 , 6308903 , 6336801 , 6364781 , 6392843 , 6420987 , 6449214 , 6477522 , 6505914 , 6534388 , 6562945 , 6591585 , 6620308 , 6649114 , 6678003 , 6706976 , 6736032 , 6765173 , 6794396 , 6823704 , 6853095 , 6882571 , 6912131 , 6941775 , 6971504 , 7001317 , 7031215 , 7061198 , 7091266 , 7121419 , 7151657 , 7181981 , 7212389 , 7242884 , 7273464 , 7304130 , 7334882 , 7365720 , 7396644 , 7427654 , 7458751 , 7489934 , 7521204 , 7552561 , 7584005 , 7615535 , 7647153 , 7678858 , 7710650 , 7742530 , 7774497 , 7806552 , 7838695 , 7870926 , 7903245 , 7935652 , 7968148 , 8000731 , 8033404 , 8066165 , 8099015 , 8131954 , 8164982 , 8198099 , 8231305 , 8264601 , 8297986 , 8331461 , 8365026 , 8398682 , 8432426 , 8466260 , 8500184 , 8534200 , 8568306 , 8602502 , 8636790 , 8671168 , 8705636 , 8740196 , 8774848 , 8809590 , 8844424 , 8879350 , 8914366 , 8949476 , 8984676 , 9019970 , 9055354 , 9090832 , 9126402 , 9162064 , 9197818 , 9233666 , 9269608 , 9305640 , 9341768 , 9377986 , 9414300 , 9450706 , 9487208 , 9523802 , 9560490 , 9597272 , 9634148 , 9671118 , 9708182 , 9745340 , 9782594 , 9819942 , 9857386 , 9894922 , 9932556 , 9970284 , 10008108 , 10046026 , 10084040 , 10122150 , 10160356 , 10198658 , 10237056 , 10275550 , 10314138 , 10352826 , 10391608 , 10430488 , 10469464 , 10508536 , 10547706 , 10586974 , 10626338 , 10665798 , 10705358 , 10745014 , 10784768 , 10824620 , 10864570 , 10904618 , 10944764 , 10985008 , 11025350 , 11065792 , 11106332 , 11146972 , 11187708 , 11228546 , 11269482 , 11310516 , 11351650 , 11392884 , 11434218 , 11475650 , 11517184 , 11558816 , 11600550 , 11642382 , 11684316 , 11726350 , 11768484 , 11810720 , 11853056 , 11895492 , 11938030}; ///Above is the values for addition. souls[0] is never used. (Array currently incomplete) int SoulTotal = 0; int LVL1 = 2; int LVL2 = 2;

LVL1 = (int)GetDlgItemInt(TextField1, LVL1, &textOkay, TRUE);

system("Pause"); cout << "Textfield1 = " << LVL1 << endl; /** Get interger from Textfields */for(int x = LVL1;x>LVL2;x++){

}

Comment: maybe you could post your code to get a more specific idea?

Comment: Exactly my point. Textfield1 and Textfield2 and the interfere were labeled.

Comment: Evil tablet keeps auto correcting correct spelling and grammar to be incorrect.

Comment: TextField1 and 2 are the handles the intergers were labeled.

Comment: Well, you are a mile from using it right.  It should resemble LVL1 = (int)GetDlgItemInt(dlgHandle, ID_LVL1, &textOkay, TRUE);  Petzold's "Programming Windows" is required reading.

Comment: dlgHandle, ID_LVL1, &textOkay these said not declared.

Comment: Please format the code you submitted. the way it stands now, it is almost unreadable. :)

Answer (score 1):

GetDlgItemInt does exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Got syntax reference?

Comment: All reference material for Win32 is in MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.aspx

Comment: [`GetDlgItemInt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645485.aspx) is a convenience function that has a number of properties that may or may not be desirable. While it offers the option to report errors, it does very little error checking. If a control's text stores the sequence *12gbn* it will simply return `12` and a success code. If more robust error detection is required, this API call will not suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I always get the string and convert it to an int. Look at the [documentation for GetWindowText()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

So first, retrieve a handle to the window of the text field:

```
HWND hText = GetDlgItem(hParent, ID_TEXT_FIELD1); // hParent is parent window of text field
```

Then, you want to get the length of the text to know how much memory to allocate and to check for a maximum/minimum length:

```
int len = GetWindowTextLength(hText);
```

Now allocate a buffer to retrieve the string from the field.

```
char* buf = new char[len + 1];
```

And retrieve the text:

```
int ret = GetWindowText(hText, buf, sizeof(buf));
```

According to the docs, ret will be greater than zero if the function succeeded, so if it is, continue and convert the buffer to an integer:

```
int LVL1 = atoi(buf); // atoi() is from stdlib.h
```

This will work assuming you made the text field only accept numbers, or parse the buffer correctly. So now you have the integer value, and you can do the same for LVL2.

Don't forget to free the buffer:

```
delete[] buf;
```

Comment: Nice detailed answer, but kinda assumes that you're not compiling for Unicode. If you are then you have buffer overflows. Possibly.

Comment: I tried this but compiler complains invalid conversion of hand to int. On hText = line.

Comment: True but it should be easy to convert it to Unicode compatible code if needed.

@WadeEuler 
The first argument is an HWND, and the second is an int value. I suspect the 2nd argument is the issue, it needs to be the window identifier passed into CreateWindow() for the text field. Since you updated your OP, I see TextField1 is the window handle and not the identifier, I'll edit my post.

Also, since you already have a handle to the text field window, there is no need for that line. Just use TextField1 in place of hText.

Comment: `sizeof(buf)` returns the size of the variable `buf`, a pointer value, i.e. either 4 or 8. While the code doesn't crash, it doesn't return the correct value either. None of this C-style hackery is necessary either, simply use a `std::vector<wchar_t>`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.